# f string formatting for python, need to combine pairs in tuple and print horizontal

Tags: python, string, format, tuples

Example code:

```
names = "tom", "maryann", "jerry", "al", "beau", "will", "joy", "bella"
```

Need it to loop through "names" and print each pair like this:
(special characters and spacing is involved, but I'm not worried about that now).

```
    tom    jerry     beau       joy  
maryann       al     will     bella
```

I don't want to use lists (if I don't have to) and I do not want to use "end=" (because I can't "tab" or use '\t'). Preferably would like to use f string and not ".format". I know all of this sounds picky, my apologies. I feel like I've done so much research and I'm coming up empty.
Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry about that, it was a misprint, it's been fixed :)
The logic is to take each two elements and pair them up vertically, side-by-side. Hope that makes sense...

Comment: I don't know much about Python, but it seems to me that when you assign multiple values to a single variable, you have an array by definition, which means it has index numbers? is there no way to iterate through the indexes and pull out the odds and the evens into two different variables then match them up? I was also thinking Regex might help but I don't know enough about Python to say how exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
names = ["tom", "maryann", "jerry", "al", "beau", "will", "joy", "bella"]
print('\t'.join(names[::2]),'\t'.join(names[1::2]) , sep='\n')
```

Or:

```
print('\t'.join(names[::2]))
print('\t'.join(names[1::2]))
```

Comment: Thank you, user1740577~ Let me play around with that for a bit and see if it will work with the special spacing...

Comment: @JoyBrock feel free for playing ;)

Answer (score 0):

First iterate the names using step as 2, that is what `::2` is doing, and print the names. Then again, do the same  thing for items in names from index `1:`.

```py
for x in names[::2]:
    print(x, end='\t')
print()
for y in names[1:][::2]:
    print(y, end='\t')
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
gary    jerry   happy   bella   
mary    alice   willow  joy
```

Comment: Thank you, ThePyGuy! But in the question, I'm trying to avoid using "end=", or lists. Any way around that?

Comment: @JoyBrock, then you can just first concatenate the string, and print at last only. But I don't think there is any valid reason for you not to use `end` parameter

Comment: As in the question there is special spacing involved for each "name"... so "\t" won't work (the amount of whitespaces is dependent upon the length of the second part of the "pair"... so it's gets weird!). I will update the question with this clarification, sorry about that :)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

I was able to get around not using any lists (which was a plus!), but not so much on the "end="... HOWEVER, I did get it to work and I was able to get it formatted horizontally with the right spacing for each row (pair).

Thank you to everyone who commented!